# Good way to test JS API Lib

Tags: javascript, web-services, api, unit-testing, testing

actually I'm writing a small JS lib to encapsulate some GET and POST calls to an external Webservice. Is there a good way / a best practice how to test such libs? 
Should I write tests against the API for the GET functions? Should I place example responses in the test directory?

P.S.: I can't send POST request to the API because it's the "LIVE" System.

Comment: Have you heard of [QUnit](https://qunitjs.com/)?

Comment: Yes. To clarify I create a lot of tests for "functional functions". This is the first time there is no real return value except the API response. The question is how to test this, when there is no DEV-API where I can fire my test against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use some sort of unit testing framework, as @BrianDriscoll commented. There are many out there.

I ran into this problem as well, and I didn't find a good AJAX mocking framework for JavaScript. I ended up creating **[Mocking Bird](https://github.com/gburghardt/mocking_bird)**.

**Advantages of Mocking Requests with MockingBird**

- It gives you fine grained control over the URL, HTTP method, status, request headers, response headers and response body
- It's easy to disable all native XMLHttpRequest calls and insert a mock object that supports the same interface without altering the code under test
- It's easy to keep native XMLHttpRequest enabled, but create a mock request and inject it into a test method
- AJAX becomes synchronous, making unit testing easier.
- MockingBird can be used with any unit testing framework
- MockingBird has no external dependencies

**Disadvantages**

- AJAX becomes synchronous. There is a possibility that the code under test could behave differently
- There is currently no way to test connection timeouts
- There is currently no way to test chunked HTTP responses
- You are not actually doing an end-to-end test with the Web Service, which will require additional integration testing (which you should be doing anyway)
- No AJAX requests will function when network connections have been disabled with MockingBird.
- It doesn't enforce the Same Domain Policy. You could mock a cross domain AJAX call that passes your unit tests, but throws an error in an integration test.

A quick and dirty example:

```
var request = new MockingBird.XMLHttpRequest()
    .returnsStatus(200)
    .returnsBody('{"message":"I am a teapot"}')
    .returnsHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "text/json"
    });

callSomeFunctionThatUsesAjax(request);

function callSomeFunctionThatUsesAjax(xhr) {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        ...
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "/foo");
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

You can also set up mock calls for cases when you cannot provide your own AJAX object:

```
MockingBird.XMLHttpRequest.disableNetworkConnections()
    .mock("/posts/123", "GET", {
        status: 404,
        body: "Page not found"
    })
    .mock("/posts/321/comments", "POST", {
        status: 201,
        responseHeaders: {
            "Content-Type": "text/json"
        },
        body: {
            post: {
                id: 321,
                comment: {
                    id: 1234
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Now your code that directly instantiates an `XMLHttpRequest` object doesn't even need to know that MockingBird exists:

```
function createComment(postId, text) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState !== 4) return;

        if (this.status === 201) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            alert("Created comment: " + data.post.comment.id);
        }
        else if (this.status === 404) {
            alert("Post " + postId + " not found!");
        }
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "/posts/" + postId);
    xhr.send("post[id]=" + postId + "&post[comment][text]=" + escape(text));
}

createComment(123, "Test Test"); // alert's "Post 123 not found!"
createComment(321, "Test Test"); // alert's "Created comment: 1234"
```

Comment: OK. Like I said I use a combination of frameworks. This is one solution I'll def. have a look at. Actually I just started with a tiny node.js server to simulate the requests and responses + errors and latency. So I can fire the automated tests (using mocha+chai+node).

Thank you Greg!